# kinvey loginwithMIC method does not open webview in mobile

Tags: kinvey

We are working on the SSO using kinvey MIC with SAML redirect. For web application we are able to achieve the result as expected. But when we use same configuration in the mobile it is not reaching the our Single Sign On Page. When I debug the webview is not refreshing the the auth url

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [following](https://github.com/bilger-progress/template-enterprise-auth-ng) to test out the **Kinvey MIC** behavior on a *NativeScript Application*.

Please make sure to:

1. Open `package.json` from inside the `src` folder and set your Application ID and Application Secret.
2. Open the `Login` component's TypeScript controller and set your **MIC** identifier.
3. Open the **MIC Service** settings from the *Kinvey Console* and set `myscheme://` as a **redirect URI**.